# minimum rank - lovasz function inequality

Tags: theta-functions, graph-theory

hey,

does the following inequality holds for every graph?

$d(G)\geq\theta(G)$

while $\theta$ is the lovasz theta function and $d(G)$ is the minimum rank over all the matrices that represent the graph $G$.

thanks everybody.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by a matrix "representing" the graph.  Lovasz discusses a certain kind of matrix representation of a graph in his paper on the subject; is that the one you mean?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean minimum rank over matrices which "fit" the graph, as described by [Haemers 1978](http://arno.uvt.nl/show.cgi?fid=80314), then the answer is no.  Note: as mentioned on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lovasz_number), there is a typo and Haemers meant that the matrix should be nonzero down the diagonal and zero in positions $(i,j)$ for which vertices are *not* adjacent.  The minimum rank over matrices which fit the graph is denoted $R(G)$.  For most graphs, $R(G) \ge \theta(G)$, however the Haemers paper gives examples where the opposite is true.